# Set values based on df.query?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to set the value of a column based on a query. I could probably use `.where` to accomplish this, but the criteria for `.query` are strings which are easier for me to maintain, especially when the criteria become complex.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(51723)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(n, 3), columns=list('abc'))
```

I'd like to make a new column, d, and set the value to 1 where these criteria are met:

```
criteria = '(a < b) & (b < c)'
```

Among other things, I've tried:

```
df['d'] = np.nan
df.query(criteria).loc[:,'d'] = 1
```

But that seems to do nothing except giving the `SettingWithCopyWarning` even though I'm using `.loc`

And passing `inplace` like this:

```
df.query(criteria, inplace=True).loc[:,'d'] = 1
```

Gives `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loc'`

Comment: what about using df2.combine_first(df1)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

AFAIK `df.query()` returns a new DF, so try the following approach:

```
In [146]: df.loc[df.eval(criteria), 'd'] = 1

In [147]: df
Out[147]:
          a         b         c    d
0  0.175155  0.221811  0.808175  1.0
1  0.069033  0.484528  0.841618  1.0
2  0.174685  0.648299  0.904037  1.0
3  0.292404  0.423220  0.897146  1.0
4  0.169869  0.395967  0.590083  1.0
5  0.574394  0.804917  0.746797  NaN
6  0.642173  0.252437  0.847172  NaN
7  0.073629  0.821715  0.859776  1.0
8  0.999789  0.833708  0.230418  NaN
9  0.028163  0.666961  0.582713  NaN
```

Comment: I missed the leaving `False` rows null part (-: