# New column values based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A" :[1,1,3,4], "B": [1,3,2,2]})
```

I want to create a new column which is C with type 1 if A = 1 & B =(1,3)
I used `.loc` and my code is

```
df.loc[(df['A'] == 1)&(df['B'] == 1), 'C'] = 'type 1'
df.loc[(df['A'] == 1)&(df['B'] == 3), 'C'] = 'type 1'
```

The above is working, but when I use

```
df.loc[(df['A'] == 1)&(df['B'] == (1,3)), 'C'] = 'type 1'
```

Nothing happens, it doesn't show error and column is also not updated.

The expected output is

```
A   B   C
1   1   type 1
1   3   type 1
3   2   Nan
4   2   Nan
```

Is there any other way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `df['B'].isin([1,3])` not `==(1,3)`.

Comment: `==(1,3)` checks whether the value is equivalent to a tuple with values `1` and `3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [1517]: import numpy as np
In [1518]: df['C'] = np.where(df.A.eq(1) & df.B.isin([1,3]), 'type 1', np.nan)

In [1519]: df
Out[1519]: 
   A  B       C
0  1  1  type 1
1  1  3  type 1
2  3  2     nan
3  4  2     nan
```

Answer (score 1):

The other ways may be to try using [`.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html#pandas.DataFrame.eval) similar to [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45470313/5916727):

```
df.loc[df.eval('A ==1 and B in [1,3]'), 'C']= 'type 1'
```

In case if you want to fix the code you have may be you can try separating with `|`:

```
df.loc[(df['A'] == 1)&((df['B'] ==1) | (df['B'] ==3)), 'C'] = 'type 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution that does not use any library but pandas:

```
df['C'] = pd.Series(index=range(len(df)), dtype='float')
df['C'][df['A'] == 1 & df['B'].isin((1, 3))] = 'type 1'
```